# Is there any way to have multiple ID:s with same name in one HTML document?

Tags: html, forms

I have a form which has several  tags.

is this possible:

```
   <select name="select1" id="select1">
       <option id="1990" value="1990">1990</option>
       <option id="1991" value="1991">1991</option>
   </select>

   <select name="select2" id="select2">
       <option id="1990" value="1990">1990</option>
       <option id="1991" value="1991">1991</option>
   </select>
```

The ID are the same...

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No id can be assigned only once since it is an **identity** for just a single element. You need to use **class** instead but i wonder why you need to assign same ids? If you assign same ids to more than one element, and use javascript, etc to manipulate it, then only last element with same id will be taken care of ignoring all previous elements....

For more information, please see:

[ID vs CLASS](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php)

Comment: To add to this: keep the ids on the select elements, remove from option elements, retreive option elements through select elements.