# Found 2 elements with non-unique id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, html5-video

I am getting the following warnings when we use with the same `id` names in two different `form` tags.

> [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id

Here is my HTML snippet:

```
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="myid-1" name="myid-1">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Job_Name" name="Job_Name" required="">
                        <label for="Job_Name">Job Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="myid-2" name="myid-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Job_Name" name="Job_Name" required="">
                        <label for="Job_Name">Job Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

How do I resolve "Found 2 elements with non-unique id" warnings?

Comment: Make the IDs unique?

Answer (score 9):

you need to change `id="Job_Name"` to be unique e.g. `id="Job_Name1" id="Job_Name2"` etc. as ID must be unique in the DOM.

It will create conflict when you want to select elements using `document.getElementById('Job_Name')` or using jQuery `$('#Job_Name')` as you wont be able to get the second  or other elements with same id. you will need to use index and querySelectorAll which will then defeat the purpose of using Id at first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Job_Name" name="Job_Name" required="" >
```

Duplicate input tag in two different forms

You have to use  different id for  different elements

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Job_Name" name="Job_Name" required="">
```

You need to change de *id* for each input

Answer (score 0):

**Becouse You mentioned the two input element with same id ('Job_Name') in same page**
You cannot give the same id in same page to two different element

Comment: There is no need to use caps like this.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is an identifier that defines the identity of the element. It is designed to act like a `key` to the element and hence it needs to be unique.

Check this answer..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187788/8230086

Answer (score 0):

Change the IDs on your inputs as they are what is causing your problem.

As a general rule you don't want to have the same id's on any of your elements.

id suggest using something along the lines of job_name1/job_name2

Answer (score 0):

> Just use new { id = "" } for one of the two fields:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "" })
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using react native web or expo pwa use nativeID in place of id

```
<input nativeID="someId"/>
```